# PHP: create a duplicate of object with references to other objects, creating duplicates of all the structure

Tags: php, object

I am writing an algorithm that is solving a puzzle. I have defined the puzzle as an object, and many other objects that are part of the puzzle. The objects are connected to each other with references. Leaving aside the memory issues of PHP with references, I have come to the following problem:

At some point, to continue solving I must engage in a trial and error. Since each move of the puzzle creates other moves, my thinking was to create a clone of my puzzle, with all its sub objects, do the trial and error there, and see if this trial and error is successfull or not.

The problem is that if I just copy the original object, it does not copy the sub objects. It keeps the references to the original sub objects. This creates the problem that when I do changes to my clone, any changes happening to its sub objects are happening on the original.

One solution that I have thought is to create a (rather complicated) function that will do the cloning (creating new sub objects to match the original).

The question is: is there an other solution that I have not thought of?

Sample code:
    class familyChild {
        public $firstname;
        public $lastname;
        public $age;
        public $param;
        public $parents;
    }

```
class familyParent {
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $age;
    public $family;
    public $children;
}

class family {
    public $parents;
    public $children;

    function doSomeTests() {
        //here we do some tests that change parameters of both the family and all its members
        //and return a value (true, false, unconclusive).
    }
}


$family1 = new family();
$family1->parents = array();
$family1->children = array();

$john = new familyChild();
$john->lastname = "Williams";
$john->firstname = "John";
$john->family = $family1;
$family1->children[] = $john;


$mary = new familyChild();
$mary->lastname = "Smith";
$mary->firstname = "Mary";
$mary->family = $family1;
$family1->children[] = $mary;


$helen = new familyParent();
$helen->lastname = "Jones";
$helen->firstname = "Helen";
$helen->family = $family1;
$family1->parents[] = $helen;


$george = new familyParent();
$george->lastname = "Smith";
$george->firstname = "Helen";
$george->family = $family1;
$family1->parents[] = $george;


//we have everyone as we want.
//but now, we want to make a clone of the whole of this family.
//in reallity I want to do calculations in a test environment, 
//without touching the original object

$mytestfamily = $family1;

$myresults = $mytestfamily->doSomeTests();

//but the problem is that because of the references,
//the $myresults has as children the original objects.
```

Comment: Did you have a look at [*Object Cloning*](https://php.net/manual/language.oop5.cloning.php)?

Comment: Yes, but as the documentation says : "When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables, will remain references." This is exactly the problem: the clone references the original. I ended up making a function that creates a clone and creates clones for each referenced child.

Comment: I asked, because in your code above you did not even use the `clone` keyword. So I wasn't sure where to start. If you have a solution, post it. It will help future visitors.